# How to debug sbt's failure "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android-4"" upon loading Android project?

Tags: android, scala, debugging, sbt, sbt-0.12

I have an android project written in Scala and java using sbt 0.12.4. When I try to load it by sbt, I get an error:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/alex/Documents/projects/android/test2/my_project/project
[error] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android-4"
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I searched for the string `android-4` but didn't find anything similar to it at all. And no other clues either.

How do I find out where the error is? Or rather, how do I debug it?

`last` doesn't help:

```
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? last
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/alex/Documents/projects/android/test2/my_project/project
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]   removed:Set()
[debug]   added: Set()
[debug]   modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] Modified external sources: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] 
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]   product: Set()
[debug]   binary dep: Set()
[debug]   external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]   
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android-4"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:231)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
  at sbtandroid.AndroidPath$$anonfun$sbtandroid$AndroidPath$$determineBuildToolsVersion$2$$anonfun$2.apply(AndroidPath.scala:22)
  at sbtandroid.AndroidPath$$anonfun$sbtandroid$AndroidPath$$determineBuildToolsVersion$2$$anonfun$2.apply(AndroidPath.scala:22)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:38)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.map(ArrayOps.scala:38)
  at sbtandroid.AndroidPath$$anonfun$sbtandroid$AndroidPath$$determineBuildToolsVersion$2.apply(AndroidPath.scala:22)
  at sbtandroid.AndroidPath$$anonfun$sbtandroid$AndroidPath$$determineBuildToolsVersion$2.apply(AndroidPath.scala:18)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:52)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.reduceLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:69)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.reduceLeft(ArrayOps.scala:38)
  at sbtandroid.AndroidPath$.sbtandroid$AndroidPath$$determineBuildToolsVersion(AndroidPath.scala:18)
  at sbtandroid.AndroidPath$$anonfun$settings$5.apply(AndroidPath.scala:40)
  at sbtandroid.AndroidPath$$anonfun$settings$5.apply(AndroidPath.scala:40)
  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
  at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$single$1.apply(INode.scala:159)
  at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$single$1.apply(INode.scala:159)
  at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:177)
  at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:132)
  at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:64)
  at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:73)
  at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:69)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[error] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android-4"
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: use last to get the full stacktrace.

Comment: @mohit, last shows no information about the actual cause.

Comment: For what it's worth, [here's something with the same problem](https://github.com/geeksville/arduleader/issues/168)...

Comment: Having looked at [AndroidPath](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/AndroidPath.scala) from android-plugin it seems that you've got something "nasty" installed under `(sdkPath / "build-tools")` and then `compareVersions` fails.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I'll check that, thanks. However, my question is mainly about how to find out the source of the error - how to debug the error, get its stack trace leading to the error.

Comment: Fixed the title to match your expectations. As to sbt and debugging such errors, I'd say the stack trace is all you've got since sbt as the execution engine for plugins got informed about the exception and I think it can't do much about it. I think it's the plugin to help sbt with additional trace messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace you get when you use last mentions `AndroidPath.scala:22` so I'd check the source of tha. The message of the exception says that the string `android-4` is not a number, so something in the android sbt plugin you are using thinks that a string containing that should contain only digits.

Search through your build config (and maybe project directories) after the string `android-4` and replace it with something that is a number and see if that helps.

If that does not help: Look at the sources of the android plugin at the specified line to see what it is doing and you may figure it out (I couldn't as I don't know what plugin and version of it you are using). You could also start sbt in debug mode and add a breakpoint in the `AndroidPath` sources.

Comment: as I said, there's no "android-4" or anything like it in the project.

Comment: Then I'd go with debugging the plugin, set a breakpoint before line 22 in AndroidPath and see if you can figure out where it gets the string from and why. Here's a blog that explains how to debug sbt: http://www.daodecode.com/blog/2013/04/19/debug-an-sbt-plugin-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: `The stack trace you get when you use last mentions AndroidPath.scala:22 so I'd check the source of that` - it's in the remote repo, how can I edit it?

Comment: You don't need to edit it, just show the sources, how it is done is different depending on the dev env you are using. In intellij there is a checkbox somewhere that says "import sources", you can get sbt to download the sources of dependencies with updateClassifiers (normal dependencies) and updateSbtClassifiers (sbt build dependencies, so this is your case), for Scala IDE I don't know.